# dropzone.js not sending image data via POST

Tags: dropzone.js

I have implemented dropzone.js with the following details:

```
Dropzone.options.addasset = {
        url: 'admin_add_asset.php',
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        paramName: 'gallery',
        autoDiscover: false,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        previewsContainer: ".gallery_images",
        parallelUploads: 100,
        maxFiles: 100,
        forceFallback: false
    };
```

and

```
<form name="addasset" id="addasset" class="dropzone" action="admin_add_asset.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

When I add a couple of files, everything looks like it works, but when the form is submitted, the $_FILES "gallery" array is not populated with the image data at all.

When I set forceFallback to true, it works fine.

Any ideas on what I may have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

have you try change the id to camelCase

and in javascriopt:

```
Dropzone.options.addAsset = {
    url: 'admin_add_asset.php',
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    paramName: 'gallery',
    autoDiscover: false,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    previewsContainer: ".gallery_images",
    parallelUploads: 100,
    maxFiles: 100,
    forceFallback: false
};
```